# What does keyword memory in function return means

Tags: solidity, memory

In some contexts, the keyword `memory` seems quite similar to a **reference type in C++**, where it gives an alias to a variable (see method 1 below). It confuses me when it's used to specify the return value data location.

I tested my code in Remix, supposedly both method 1 and 2 would return same values. However method 2 returns **an array of all zeros**. Could somebody tell me what's happening here?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract Test3 {
    struct A {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
    }
    
    // method 1: assigning values in the loop
    function LoopThrough() external pure returns (A[] memory _A) {
        _A =  new A[](5);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i< 5; ++i) {
            A memory _memoryA = _A[i];
            _memoryA.a = 123;
            _memoryA.b = 456;
        } 
    }

    // method 2: assigning value in another function
    function LoopThrough2() external pure returns (A[] memory _A) {
        _A =  new A[](5);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i< 5; ++i) {
            A memory _memoryA = _A[i];
            _memoryA = _internalReturn();
        } 
    }

    // helper function
    function _internalReturn() internal pure returns (A memory _a) {
        _a.a = 123;
        _a.b = 456;
    }
}
```

### Edit 1

In C++, method 2 seems to be working. Here's a link to C++ code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d3aK3T83c).

Comment: The memory keyword only references where the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call an instance of the struct `A` an 'object' for the purpose of this example I'm going to explain to you.

With this line:

```js
A memory _memoryA = _A[i];
```

The variable `_memoryA` contains a reference to the 'object' in the array `_A` at index `i`. The `_memoryA` variable is not the object, it just has a reference to the object, and the object can be modified through it, doing what you are doing in your `LoopThrough` function, like `_memoryA.a = 123;`. That's fine, that works.

The problem of the `LoopThrough2` function is that it does not modify the 'object' through the reference that the `_memoryA` variable has, it completely replaces the reference to the object at index `_A[1]` with the reference of a new `A` 'object' created and returned in the function `_internalReturn()`. So, the 'object' at index `_A[1]` is not be modified by this because it was not modified using the dot operator like `aReference.property = value`.

You could assign this new object to the index of the other object if you want, like:

```js
function LoopThrough2() external pure returns (A[] memory _A) {
        _A =  new A[](5);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i< 5; ++i) {
            _A[i] = _internalReturn(); // Like this
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I don't understand `it completely replaces the reference to the object ... with the reference of a new ...`. Since the left hand side is a reference, and the right hand side is the new object, shouldn't the new object be assigned to the reference, which is `_A[i]`? I updated my question with a C++ example to illustrate my idea.